# Control electrical switch from Android app

Tags: android

I have a requirement to control an electrical switch which turns on/off the current to an electrical device. The switch is a simple switch like a light bulb switch. The switch has no interfaces like USB, Bluetooth etc. through which we can connect and turn on and off the switch. So I want to know about what possible options are there I can make use of?

Comment: You need to create a device in which you can get control comments from android and which can send that comments to other device with connect to light, The device which connected to light can able to control the current accordingly

Comment: Use an SCR (to close the high power contact) connected to an Arduino and use a bluetooth module (to connect the Arduino to Android).

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at *Raspberry Pi* (RPI).
I suppose the flow would be something like 
Android app > Wifi Network > Raspberry Pi > Actuator > Light on/off

This should allow you to control the bulb remotely.
There are lots of tutorial you can find on the web about how to implement this using the RPI.